# Efficiently find every combination of assigning smaller bins to larger bins

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, graph-theory, mathematical-optimization

Let's say I have 7 small bins, each bin has the following number of marbles in it:

```
var smallBins = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 4, 10];
```

I assign these small bins to 2 large bins, each with the following maximum capacity:

```
var largeBins = [40, 50];
```

I want to find EVERY combination of how the small bins can be distributed across the big bins without exceeding capacity (eg put small bins #4,#5 in large bin #2, the rest in #1).

Constraints:

- Each small bin must be assigned to a large bin.
- A large bin can be left empty

This problem is easy to solve in <strike>O(n^m)</strike> O(2^n) time (see below): just try every combination and if capacity is not exceeded, save the solution. I'd like something faster, that can handle a variable number of bins. What obscure graph theory algorithm can I use to reduce the search space?

```
//Brute force
var smallBins = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 4, 10];
var largeBins = [40, 50];

function getLegitCombos(smallBins, largeBins) {
  var legitCombos = [];
  var assignmentArr = new Uint32Array(smallBins.length);
  var i = smallBins.length-1;
  while (true) {
    var isValid = validate(assignmentArr, smallBins, largeBins);
    if (isValid) legitCombos.push(new Uint32Array(assignmentArr));
    var allDone = increment(assignmentArr, largeBins.length,i);
    if (allDone === true) break;
  }
  return legitCombos;
}

function increment(assignmentArr, max, i) {
  while (i >= 0) {
    if (++assignmentArr[i] >= max) {
      assignmentArr[i] = 0;
      i--;
    } else {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function validate(assignmentArr, smallBins, largeBins) {
  var totals = new Uint32Array(largeBins.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < smallBins.length; i++) {
    var assignedBin = assignmentArr[i];
    totals[assignedBin] += smallBins[i];
    if (totals[assignedBin] > largeBins[assignedBin]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
getLegitCombos(smallBins, largeBins);
```

Comment: are you sure your code is O(n^m)? Because each there exist 2^n combinations and in the worst case the algorithm needs to return them all.

Comment: i may be mistaken on that... check my reasoning: each small bin, m, can be assigned to each big bin n for a total of n^m.

Comment: You've heard of the so called [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)? Good luck at finding a more efficient solution - you can win a lot of money :-)

Comment: Thankfully this is a lot simpler than a bin packing problem. I could use a few of the same principles (eg sort bins greatest to least, if capacity is exceeded, skip trying to add the smaller values to it) but I think there exists something that knocks it down by an order of magnitude, kinda like the hungarian algo for the assignment problem.

Comment: Sorry Matt, it's indeed `O(2^n)` just to find the solution for one of the large bins (even if you leave the other empty). It's actually a little harder, not easier than bin packing. Basically you solve the problem for both large bins separately (treating the other bin as empty as given by second constraint), then you can combine the results in `O(n*(a + b)) = O(2^N)`, where `a` and `b` are the number of combinations for each of the two large bins.

Comment: that makes sense, I'm terrible at time complexities. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my cumbersome recursive attempt to avoid duplicates and exit early from too large sums. The function assumes duplicate elements as well as bin sizes are presented grouped and counted in the input. Rather than place each element in each bin, each element is placed in only one of duplicate bins; and each element with duplicates is partitioned distinctly.

For example, in my results, the combination, `[[[1,10,20]],[[4,5,10,30]]]` appears once; while in the SAS example in Leo's answer, twice: once as `IN[1]={1,3,4} IN[2]={2,5,6,7}` and again as `IN[1]={1,4,7} IN[2]={2,3,5,6}`.

Can't vouch for efficiency or smooth-running, however, as it is hardly tested. Perhaps stacking the calls rather than recursing could weigh lighter on the browser.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f (as,bs){

  // i is the current element index, c its count; 
  // l is the lower-bound index of partitioned element
  function _f(i,c,l,sums,res){

    for (var j=l; j<sums.length; j++){
      // find next available duplicate bin to place the element in
      var k=0;
      while (sums[j][k] + as[i][0] > bs[j][0]){
        k++;
      }

      // a place for the element was found          
      if (sums[j][k] !== undefined){
        var temp = JSON.stringify(sums),
            _sums = JSON.parse(temp);
        _sums[j][k] += as[i][0];

        temp = JSON.stringify(res);           
        var _res = JSON.parse(temp);

        _res[j][k].push(as[i][0]);

        // all elements were placed
        if (i == as.length - 1 && c == 1){
          result.push(_res);
          return;

        // duplicate elements were partitioned, continue to next element
        } else if (c == 1){
          _f(i + 1,as[i + 1][1],0,_sums,_res);

        // otherwise, continue partitioning the same element with duplicates
        } else {
          _f(i,c - 1,j,_sums,_res);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // initiate variables for the recursion 
  var sums = [],
      res = []
      result = [];

  for (var i=0; i<bs.length; i++){
    sums[i] = [];
    res[i] = [];
    for (var j=0; j<bs[i][1]; j++){
      sums[i][j] = 0;
      res[i][j] = [];
    }  
  }

  _f(0,as[0][1],0,sums,res);
  return result;
}
```

Output:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[1,1],[4,1],[5,1],[10,2],[20,1],[30,1]], [[40,1],[50,1]])));

/*
[[[[1,4,5,10,10]],[[20,30]]],[[[1,4,5,10,20]],[[10,30]]],[[[1,4,5,20]],[[10,10,30]]]
,[[[1,4,5,30]],[[10,10,20]]],[[[1,4,10,20]],[[5,10,30]]],[[[1,4,30]],[[5,10,10,20]]]
,[[[1,5,10,20]],[[4,10,30]]],[[[1,5,30]],[[4,10,10,20]]],[[[1,10,20]],[[4,5,10,30]]]
,[[[1,30]],[[4,5,10,10,20]]],[[[4,5,10,20]],[[1,10,30]]],[[[4,5,30]],[[1,10,10,20]]]
,[[[4,10,20]],[[1,5,10,30]]],[[[4,30]],[[1,5,10,10,20]]],[[[5,10,20]],[[1,4,10,30]]]
,[[[5,30]],[[1,4,10,10,20]]],[[[10,10,20]],[[1,4,5,30]]],[[[10,20]],[[1,4,5,10,30]]]
,[[[10,30]],[[1,4,5,10,20]]],[[[30]],[[1,4,5,10,10,20]]]]
*/

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[1,1],[4,1],[5,1],[10,2],[20,1],[30,1]], [[20,2],[50,1]])));

/*
[[[[1,4,5,10],[10]],[[20,30]]],[[[1,4,5,10],[20]],[[10,30]]],[[[1,4,5],[20]],[[10,10,30]]]
,[[[1,4,10],[20]],[[5,10,30]]],[[[1,5,10],[20]],[[4,10,30]]],[[[1,10],[20]],[[4,5,10,30]]]
,[[[4,5,10],[20]],[[1,10,30]]],[[[4,10],[20]],[[1,5,10,30]]],[[[5,10],[20]],[[1,4,10,30]]]
,[[[10,10],[20]],[[1,4,5,30]]],[[[10],[20]],[[1,4,5,10,30]]]]
*/
```

Here's a second, simpler version that only attempts to terminate the thread when an element cannot be placed:

```js
function f (as,bs){

  var stack = [],
      sums = [],
      res = []
      result = [];

  for (var i=0; i<bs.length; i++){
    res[i] = [];
    sums[i] = 0;
  }

  stack.push([0,sums,res]);

  while (stack[0] !== undefined){
    var params = stack.pop(),
        i = params[0],
        sums = params[1],
        res = params[2];

    for (var j=0; j<sums.length; j++){
      if (sums[j] + as[i] <= bs[j]){
        var _sums = sums.slice();
        _sums[j] += as[i];

        var temp = JSON.stringify(res);
        var _res = JSON.parse(temp);

        _res[j].push(i);

        if (i == as.length - 1){
          result.push(_res);

        } else {
          stack.push([i + 1,_sums,_res]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Output:

```
var r = f([1,5,10,20,30,4,10,3,4,5,1,1,2],[40,50,30]);
console.log(r.length)

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,4,5,10,10,20,30], [40,50])));

162137 

[[[30],[1,4,5,10,10,20]],[[10,30],[1,4,5,10,20]],[[10,20],[1,4,5,10,30]]
,[[10,30],[1,4,5,10,20]],[[10,20],[1,4,5,10,30]],[[10,10,20],[1,4,5,30]]
,[[5,30],[1,4,10,10,20]],[[5,10,20],[1,4,10,30]],[[5,10,20],[1,4,10,30]]
,[[4,30],[1,5,10,10,20]],[[4,10,20],[1,5,10,30]],[[4,10,20],[1,5,10,30]]
,[[4,5,30],[1,10,10,20]],[[4,5,10,20],[1,10,30]],[[4,5,10,20],[1,10,30]]
,[[1,30],[4,5,10,10,20]],[[1,10,20],[4,5,10,30]],[[1,10,20],[4,5,10,30]]
,[[1,5,30],[4,10,10,20]],[[1,5,10,20],[4,10,30]],[[1,5,10,20],[4,10,30]]
,[[1,4,30],[5,10,10,20]],[[1,4,10,20],[5,10,30]],[[1,4,10,20],[5,10,30]]
,[[1,4,5,30],[10,10,20]],[[1,4,5,20],[10,10,30]],[[1,4,5,10,20],[10,30]]
,[[1,4,5,10,20],[10,30]],[[1,4,5,10,10],[20,30]]]
```

Comment: this looks great, allow me a little time to digest it & I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: I have no idea if it works, lol. if you end up testing it, please let me know if there's an issue

Comment: For my use case, doesn't look like it will work unfortunately. Reason is that each small bag of marbles is a unique object so bag A with 10 marbles !== bag B with 10 marbles.

Comment: @MattK nothing prevents you from placing both in my code, e.g., doing it either way `[10,1],[10,1]` or `[10,2]`, or even `[10,1],[10,1],[10,2]` - I think the first one should suit the purpose you described. The version you describe could have slightly simpler code, with less layered objects. Would you want to consider bins of the same size as unique as well?

Comment: With larger sample sizes, it stops returning all the results. For example: `smallBins = [[1,1],[5,1],[10,1],[20,1],[30,1],[4,1],[10,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[1,1],[1,1],[2,1]];
bigBins = [[40,1],[50,1],[30,1]];` 
returns 64387 results when it should return 162137.

Comment: @MattK where did you get the 162137 number from, does it include duplicates where elements are just in a different position rather than a different bin?

Comment: from the brute force solution in the question (granted, it could be wrong!)

Comment: @MattK I think the discrepancy for larger parameters was caused by JavaScript recursion limits. I revised the second, simpler version in my answer to an iterative stack approach. Our results now seem to match. Yours took 3430 milliseconds on my browser and mine 2707.

Comment: i like it! looks like by keeping partial sums stored you can reduce the time required to validate.

Comment: @MattK thanks, perhaps there's some more optimizations that can be done related to how the data is being stored while iterated, but anyway that's a general idea.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is seen often enough that most Constraint Logic Programming systems include a predicate to model it explicitly. In OPTMODEL and CLP, we call it [pack](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ormpug/68156/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ormpug_clpsolver_syntax10.htm):

```
proc optmodel;
    set SMALL init 1 .. 7, LARGE init 1 .. 2;
    num size    {SMALL} init [1 5 10 20 30 4 10];
    num capacity{LARGE} init [40 50];

    var WhichBin {i in SMALL} integer >= 1 <= card(LARGE);
    var SpaceUsed{i in LARGE} integer >= 0 <= capacity[i];

    con pack( WhichBin, size, SpaceUsed );

    solve with clp / findall;

    num soli;
    set IN{li in LARGE} = {si in SMALL: WhichBin[si].sol[soli] = li}; 
    do soli = 1 .. _nsol_;
        put IN[*]=;
    end;
quit;
```

This code produces all the solutions in 0.06 seconds on my laptop:

```
IN[1]={1,2,3,4,6} IN[2]={5,7}
IN[1]={1,2,3,4} IN[2]={5,6,7}
IN[1]={1,2,3,6,7} IN[2]={4,5}
IN[1]={1,2,5,6} IN[2]={3,4,7}
IN[1]={1,2,5} IN[2]={3,4,6,7}
IN[1]={1,2,4,6,7} IN[2]={3,5}
IN[1]={1,2,4,7} IN[2]={3,5,6}
IN[1]={1,2,4,6} IN[2]={3,5,7}
IN[1]={1,3,4,6} IN[2]={2,5,7}
IN[1]={1,3,4} IN[2]={2,5,6,7}
IN[1]={1,5,6} IN[2]={2,3,4,7}
IN[1]={1,5} IN[2]={2,3,4,6,7}
IN[1]={1,4,6,7} IN[2]={2,3,5}
IN[1]={1,4,7} IN[2]={2,3,5,6}
IN[1]={2,3,4,6} IN[2]={1,5,7}
IN[1]={2,3,4} IN[2]={1,5,6,7}
IN[1]={2,5,6} IN[2]={1,3,4,7}
IN[1]={2,5} IN[2]={1,3,4,6,7}
IN[1]={2,4,6,7} IN[2]={1,3,5}
IN[1]={2,4,7} IN[2]={1,3,5,6}
IN[1]={3,5} IN[2]={1,2,4,6,7}
IN[1]={3,4,7} IN[2]={1,2,5,6}
IN[1]={3,4,6} IN[2]={1,2,5,7}
IN[1]={3,4} IN[2]={1,2,5,6,7}
IN[1]={5,7} IN[2]={1,2,3,4,6}
IN[1]={5,6} IN[2]={1,2,3,4,7}
IN[1]={5} IN[2]={1,2,3,4,6,7}
IN[1]={4,6,7} IN[2]={1,2,3,5}
IN[1]={4,7} IN[2]={1,2,3,5,6}
```

Just change the first 3 lines to solve for other instances. However, as others have pointed out, this problem is NP-Hard. So it can switch from very fast to very slow suddenly. You could also solve the version where not every small item needs to be assigned to a large bin by creating a dummy large bin with enough capacity to fit the entire collection of small items.

As you can see from the "Details" section in the manual, the algorithms that solve practical problems quickly are not simple, and their implementation details make a big difference. I am unaware of any CLP libraries written in Javascript. Your best bet may be to wrap CLP in a web service and invoke that service from your Javascript code.

Comment: wow, that's it alright. Thanks for pointing the way! Do you know if this particular constraint satisfaction problem has a name? I've got to imagine there's a C/Java implementation I can port over.

Comment: The name varies. I'd call it Bin Packing into Variable Pack Sizes. There are probably implementations in C and Java; but separating them from the broader context of Constraint Satisfaction is likely to be too hard to be worth it.